# Help with Cavalier/mount special abilities

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, animal-companions, mount

I'm building a Cavalier in Pathfinder, and under the "mount" section in the APG it talks about the mount dying, then says, "New mount does not gain the link, evasion, devotion, or improved evasion special abilities..." But these are the only mention of those abilities that I find anywhere in the information about the Cavalier class. Was the original mount supposed to have had those abilities?  What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take the [tour]. Yes, *Pathfinder* can be awfully spread out, with information scattered everywhere. Thanks for your participation, and have fun.

Answer (score 5):

A [cavalier](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/cavalier)'s [mount](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/cavalier#TOC-Mount-Ex-) functions as the [druid](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid)'s [animal companion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/animal-companions), so the mount gains the special abilities and other stuff as the cavalier levels up according to the linked [animal companion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/animal-companions) table.

For example, a level 6 cavalier's mount has the special abilities link, share spells, evasion, ability score increase, and devotion, but were that mount to die, the mount the cavalier discovers after 1 week of mourning doesn't gain the special abilities link, evasion, and devotion until the cavalier himself becomes level 7.